# how to limit a parameter to only one variant of a variant type

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, algebraic-data-types, gadt, reason

Suppose I have two types, `Vector2D` and `Vector3D` and they are tagged (that's the correct term, right?), and I want to write a function that operates ONLY on `Vector2D` (or is `vector(two)` more correct here?), like this:

```
type two;
type three;
type vector('a) = 
  | Vector2D(float, float): vector(two)
  | Vector3D(float, float, float): vector(three);

let first = (a: vector(two)) => {
  switch(a) {
    | (x, y) => x +. y
  }
}

let second = (Vector2D(x, y)) => {
  x +. y
}

let third = ((x, y): vector(two)) => {
  x +.y
}
```

The `first` and `second` functions prohibit passing a `Vector3D`, just as I want but they raise a warning "This pattern matching is not exhaustive".

For `first` I'd like to know why this is not exhaustive, have I not limited the possible options to `Vector2D` here? For `second` I guess the reason is the same as for `first`, but how would it even be possible to solve the issue with this syntax?

As for `third`, this one does not compile because "This pattern matches ('a, 'b) but vector(two) was expected". Why does the compiler expect any tuple here? Is it not possible to use destructuring in function parameters?

EDIT:
Turns out there's an even simpler problem to demonstrate what I want

```
type state = Solid | Liquid
let splash = (object) => {
  switch(object) {
    | Liquid => "splashing sounds. I guess."
    | Solid => "" // this should not even be possible in the context of this function, and I want to compiler to enforce this
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning the GADT part, the issue here is that you are using bucklescript and its ancient 4.02.3 compiler version. 
For instance, the following code works perfectly fine in OCaml ≥ 4.03 :

```
type two = Two ; 
type three = Three ;
/* Never define abstract types when you want to use them as type level tags,
  your code will only works inside the module defining them, and then
  fail due to injectivity problems.
*/

type vector('a) = 
  | Vector2D(float, float): vector(two)
  | Vector3D(float, float, float): vector(three);

let sum_2 = (Vector2D(x,y)) => x +. y
let sum_3 = (Vector3D(x,y,z)) => x +. y +. z 
let sum_any = (type a, x: vector(a) ) => switch (x) {
  | Vector2D(x,y) => x +. y;
  | Vector3D(x,y,z) => x +. y +. z
}
```

But it will fail on 4.02.3 with an exhaustiveness warning(which should be treated as an error), because exhaustiveness check for GADTs with refutation clauses was only added in 4.03 .

Comment: after updating to bs-platform@5.2.1 and applying the changes regarding the abstract types I was able to achieve the desired behaviour, thanks.

Comment: Oh, this is awesome. I did not realize this was added far back in 4.03. I guess I'm an ancient dinosaur too now. This means a lot of uses for polymorphic variants can be replaced with GADTs, avoiding the complicated subtyping rules of the former.

Comment: @DanielPotensky I think you mean bs-platform@6.2.1, as 5.2.1 should still be on 4.02.3.

Comment: @glennsl that's very interesting because I just checked and I really have 5.2.1 in my lockfile... how do you check what ocaml compiler version is used under the hood?

Comment: @DanielPotensky `bsc -version`. Or `npx bsc -version` to check the one installed locally in the project. The defining difference between the 5.x and 6.x series is that the former uses 4.02.3 while the latter uses 4.06.1.

Comment: @glennsl that is indeed interesting, shows `BuckleScript 5.2.1 ( Using OCaml:4.02.3+BS )` yet it works as expected? Maybe the only change necessary was the `type two = Two;`?

Comment: Well, now I'm not sure what's going on either. Your example seems to work fine now on 4.02.3 too (except for the tuple patterns), but I'm sure I got exhaustiveness warnings on it yesterday. Granted it was late, but it wasn't _that_ late.

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that the 4.02.3 algorithm barely works in this very specific case, and only fails with three constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want using [polymorphic variants](https://2ality.com/2018/01/polymorphic-variants-reasonml.html):

```rust
type vector = [
  | `Vector2D(float, float)
  | `Vector3D(float, float, float)
];

let first = (a: [`Vector2D(float, float)]) => {
  switch(a) {
    | `Vector2D(x, y) => x +. y
  }
}

let second = (`Vector2D(x, y)) => {
  x +. y
}
```

This will give you a type error if you try to pass a `` `Vector3D `` to either function:

```
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type [> `Vector3d(float, float, float) ]
       but an expression was expected of type [< `Vector2D(float, float) ]
       The second variant type does not allow tag(s) `Vector3d
```

Note first that `Vector2D` and `Vector3D` in your example are not types. They are constructors which construct values of the `vector('a)` type. They are sometimes also called "tags", as you rightly point out, and the type is sometimes called a "tagged union" instead of "variant" because values contain a tag that specifies which constructor was used to construct it. The tag is what's checked when you pattern match using a constructor pattern.

What you're using in your example is not an ordinary variant, but a [Generalized Algebraic Data Type (GADT)](https://sketch.sh/s/yH0MJiujNSiofDWOU85loX/) (which might have been more aptly named "Generalized Variant" in OCaml/Reason), <s>and the reason it does not work is that, while a GADT allows you to assign a specific type to a constructor, it does not work the other way around. You can have several constructors that specify `vector(two)`for example.</s> (Edit: This seems to be wrong, see @octachron's answer)

Neither the `first` or `third` function in your example compiles, The compiler expects a tuple because you use a tuple pattern instead of a constructor pattern. `(x, y)` is not the same as `Vector2D(x, y)`. If it was, you wouldn't be able to distinguish `Vector2D(float, float)` from `Line(point, point)`, for example, which contains data of an entirely different type.